# While looping with dynamic CSV in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, loops, csv, date, sqlplus

I'm new at sqlplus and I need a help. I have the select below, and I want to add a While looping to generate a CSV file for each day of the period.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

```
set pagesize 0
set colsep '|'
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set trimspool on
set headsep off

define start_date = '01/01/2004'
define end_date = '02/01/2004'
define start_csv = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&start_date.','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
define end_csv = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&start_date.','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')

spool 'C:\Extracted_&start_csv._&end_csv..csv'

SELECT <MY SELECT>
FROM <MY TABLES>
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '&start_date.' AND '&end_date.'

spool OFF;

SET echo ON
SET feedback ON
SET headsep ON
```

EDIT 1: Here my first attempt in PL/SQL version:

```
DECLARE
    -- I pretend to use this variable later, that's why I sent the value to ACTUAL_DATE to run the looping
    START_DATE DATE := '01/01/2004';
    END_DATE DATE := '31/12/2009';
    ACTUAL_DATE DATE := START_DATE;
    DT VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
    WHILE ACTUAL_DATE <= END_DATE LOOP
        DT := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ACTUAL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        --sqlplus only
        --SPOOL 'C:\EXTRACTED_&DT..CSV'

        SELECT <MY SELECT>
        FROM <MY TABLES>
        WHERE DATE = '&ACTUAL_DATE.'

        --SPOOL OFF;
        ACTUAL_DATE := ACTUAL_DATE + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Looping is a procedural thing. So you need to use PL/SQL instead, which entails a bunch of changes. Or write a shell script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already created a version for PL/SQL, but in this way, my problem changed to generate the spool as the SPOOL command is not recognized by PL/SQL

Comment: Yes, that's the "bunch of changes" and that's why I suggested a shell script. There is no way to do this in pure SQL / SQL*Plus except by running the script for each day.

Comment: And how this will work in shell script? Do you have a link to study?

Comment: As an aside, let me point out that your 'dates' aren't dates, but character strings, and comparing them will be  string comparison, not a date comparison.   As such, '01/02/2020' comes _before_  '12/01/1975'.  Not what you want.  Your "DATE" column should be of type DATE, and all your data handling should be done as DATEs not VARCHARs.

Comment: Back on the original question ... where do the two input dates come from and how do they find their way into the script?

Comment: @EdStevens sorry, I don't get your question. I have the two variables start_date and end_date filled up with the period I need to extract from database and at WHERE statement I use these values to generate this CSV. 

Contextualizing: I need to extract 5 years of data and don't want to babysitting changing the data and running the script every month, so I want extract the data per day (this way if I lost the connection I won't lose much data) and after I'll use all these data into a Data Analytics software.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL code to generate the script.  For example, the following SQL statement will generate a SQL*Plus script for spooling DBA_OBJECTS created on a day by day basis to separate .csv files:

```
with head as (select 0 ord, 'set echo off linesize 200 pagesize 2000 heading off feedback off' cmd from dual)
, main as
(
select rownum ord, cmd 
from 
(
select 'spool c:\temp\csv_'||to_char(trunc(created),'YYYY_MM_DD')||'.csv'
|| chr(13)||chr(10) ||
'select owner || '','' || object_type|| '','' || object_name from dba_objects where trunc(created) = to_date(''' || to_char(trunc(created),'YYYY_MM_DD') || ''', ''YYYY_MM_DD''' || ') order by owner, object_type, object_name ; '
|| chr(13)||chr(10) ||
'spool off ' 
|| chr(13)||chr(10) 
|| chr(13)||chr(10) as cmd
from DBA_objects
where created between sysdate-15 and sysdate
group by trunc(created)
order by trunc(created)
)
)
, script as (select * from head union select * from main)
select cmd from script order by ord
;
```